# 'MYPROGRAM.IO.MemoryStream' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' Error?

Tags: c#, windows

So I am trying to code something that goes to a link, but changes the middle part with what a user types. Such as:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new IO.MemoryStream(new System.Net.Webclient().DownloadData("http://api.skype.com/users/" + textBox6.Text + "/profile/avatar")));
```

for my Skype tool I'm making, but the only problem I get is `MemoryStream`. It says

> 'MYPROGRAMNAME.IO.MemoryStream' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

I don't know what's wrong. I can't find anything.

Comment: or i mean It grabs a image from a Link from what a user types (textbox6)

Comment: Did you create your own IO class?  `MYPROGRAMNAME.IO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you have created another property IO.MemoryStream in your project. Instead you should use `System.IO.MemoryStream` namespace. See modified below.

```
pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://api.skype.com/users/" + textBox6.Text + "/profile/avatar")));
```

Comment: when i use the code you entered it now gives me a namespace error

Comment: @AaronMendoza Your screen shot shows `Webclient` when it should be `WebClient`.  How did you get that to compile?

Comment: I honestly don't know but i copied yours and it's now working Thanks :)

Comment: Look like some namespace issue. Because System.IO.MemoryStream class exist since 1.1 framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx